# Dura Ace 7800/7900 vs 9000

Tags: brakes, shimano, shifter

I have Dura Ace 9000 mechanical shifters and I'd love to have hoods that aren't black.  The only product I've found are [Hudz](http://odigrips.com/store/road) but they only fit 7800 and 7900.  Obviously there was enough of a change between the 7800s and 7900s to warrant a new mold, but does this apply to the 9000s too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, different. There's [at least one company](https://www.officinescagliarini.com/product/scagliarini-colored-brakes-hoods-for-shimano-st-9000-11s/) doing colorful ST-R9000 hoods.

Comment: If there's at least one company that's suggests there's more, can you edit the accepted answer to at least include an image or example. If the one link you have provided goes 404 we have an accepted answer with no relevant info whatsoever in its current form

Comment: That they're different form factors is "relevant info" in that it is the piece of information the question is asking about.